# No sound... How to re-enable pulseaudio?

Tags: installation, sound, pulseaudio

Ok, back when I had 12, I was using Pulseaudio equalizer, and it worked great. but now the I have 13.04, It doesn't work, and there are no options under "play sound through", where it used to say speakers, or headphones, when I had them plugged in. I assume this means I need to re-enable pulseaudio. how do I do so? I've tried Reinstalling, and that has proven ineffective. (PS: it works fine in the guest account. it's just in this user that it's not working for some reason.)

More: When I type "Pulseaudio" in a terminal I get:   E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.

Comment: tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio` ?

Comment: Tried that, no dice. anything else I should try? maybe a code to run it? I'm just learning this stuff, so I apologize if I'm asking stupid questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you say it works fine as guest, just run `rm -rf ~/.pulse` from your terminal. That would wipe your pulseaudio settings as the currently logged in user.

Comment: So just type that into my terminal?

Comment: Never type/paste anything into your terminal from the internet if you don't fully understand what you are doing!

Comment: ...right. that's probably what happened in the first place. so then what does that do?

Comment: Intriguing question. If there was a simple solution for this, we'd all be using linux by now. :) A good approach is that you focus on 2 things: a, your computer is not compromised (security-wise), b, you can recover from the operation. Since the above is a simple rm, all you have to do is make a backup of the directory that you would remove and then just go on; you can always roll it back.

Comment: Well I fixed it. I uninstalled it, and left it uninstalled for a while, then reinstalled it, and now it works. why reinstalling it the first 3 times didn't fix it, idk. but this time the little toolbar icon is gone, on all  users. but sound works on all users.